# Calculate group result and merge it with details

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2014

Please consider this result (Report):

```
State       Value1       Value2        Value3
---------------------------------------------
State1        103         23%            3
State2        105         32%            12
State3        150         2%             23
Group1        120         19%            3
===================
State4        200         40%            5
State5        250         2%             12
Group2        225         21%            8
===================
...
```

I have groups and each group contains some states. No I want to run a query on my details data and run some custom function on each group to obtain `Value1` to `Value3`. For simplicity consider `AVG` function.

I'm using `Group By` clause to generate states result but how I can merge group of states with my result?

Thanks

**Edit 1)**

this is the basic Data and this may not match above output:

```
Id      StateName      Value1       Value2      Value3
1       State1           1             2          3
2       State2           4             2          2
3       State2           3             3          8
4       State2           3             8          5
...
```

---

**Edit 2)**

For Example :

```
State1, State2, State3 Belong to `Group1`
State4, state5 Belong to `Group2`
...
```

Comment: Please provide sample data (DDL).

Comment: What output you need from this input?

Comment: What's your current T-SQL statement?

Comment: How you apply group, on which column?

Comment: @PawanKumar I've already mentioned the output above(First Code Block)

Comment: @SandipPatel I use `Group By` clause on `StateName` column to get basic States result but I want to calculate group of states result and generate above result

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I added the basic data and structure

Comment: How you tell which states belongs to certain group?

Comment: @gotqn I added Edit 2 for sample grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking as below, I have used [ROLLUP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx) function to achive functionality.

```
DECLARE @tblStates AS Table
(
    GroupName VARCHAR(10),
    StateName VARCHAR(50),
    Value1 INT,
    Value2 INT,
    Value3 INT
)   

INSERT INTO @tblStates VALUES('Group1','State1',103,23,3)
INSERT INTO @tblStates VALUES('Group1','State2',105,32,12)
INSERT INTO @tblStates VALUES('Group1','State3',150,2,23)
INSERT INTO @tblStates VALUES('Group2','State3',50,10,8)
INSERT INTO @tblStates VALUES('Group2','State4',80,22,1)
INSERT INTO @tblStates VALUES('Group2','State5',20,18,45)

;WITH T as
(
    SELECT
        GroupName,
        StateName,
        AVG(Value1) AS Value1,
        AVG(Value2) AS Value2,
        MIN(Value3) AS Value3
    FROM @tblStates
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(GroupName,StateName)        
)
SELECT 
    CASE ISNULL(StateName,'') WHEN '' THEN GroupName ELSE StateName END AS StateName,
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3      
FROM T  
WHERE 
T.GroupName IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY GroupName
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the [GROUPING SETS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx). This functionality allows you to perform aggregation in one statement grouping by different values in the same `GROUP BY` clause.

So, I guess you need something like this (first add in your data to which group it belongs):

```
Id      StateName      Value1       Value2      Value3  Group
1       State1           1             2          3     Group01
2       State2           4             2          2     Group01
3       State2           3             3          8     Group01
4       State4           3             8          5     Group02
...
```

Then, you will have:

```
SELECT ISNULL([Group],[StateName])
      ,AVG()
FROM ...
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
(
    ([Group])
   ,([Group], [StateName])
);
```