# ROLLUP, Different rounding in grand total

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, common-table-expression, rollup

Related to: [Calculate group result and merge it with details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48637240/calculate-group-result-and-merge-it-with-details/48637883#48637883)

The problem is I want different rounding precision in grand total. please consider this code:

```
DECLARE @tblStates AS Table
(
    StateName VARCHAR(50),
    Value1 DECIMAL(5,2),
    Value2 DECIMAL(5,2),
    Value3 DECIMAL(5,2)
)   

INSERT INTO @tblStates VALUES('State1',103,23,3)
INSERT INTO @tblStates VALUES('State2',105,32,12)
INSERT INTO @tblStates VALUES('State3',150,2,23)
INSERT INTO @tblStates VALUES('State4',50,10,8)
INSERT INTO @tblStates VALUES('State5',80,22,1)
INSERT INTO @tblStates VALUES('State6',20,18,45)

DECLARE @tblStatesGroups AS Table
(
    [Group] VARCHAR(50),
    [State] VARCHAR(50)
)   

INSERT INTO @tblStatesGroups VALUES('Group1','State1')
INSERT INTO @tblStatesGroups VALUES('Group1','State2')
INSERT INTO @tblStatesGroups VALUES('Group1','State3')
INSERT INTO @tblStatesGroups VALUES('Group2','State4')
INSERT INTO @tblStatesGroups VALUES('Group2','State5')
INSERT INTO @tblStatesGroups VALUES('Group2','State6')

;WITH T as
(
    SELECT
        groups.[Group],
        StateName,
        AVG(Value1) AS Value1,
        AVG(Value2) AS Value2,
        MIN(Value3) AS Value3
    FROM @tblStates states inner join @tblStatesGroups groups on states.StateName = groups.[State]
GROUP BY ROLLUP(groups.[Group],StateName)        
)
SELECT 
    CASE ISNULL(StateName,'') WHEN '' THEN [Group] ELSE StateName END AS StateName,
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3      
FROM T  
ORDER BY [Group]
```

I want sub totals have 1 decimal point precision and grand total has 2 decimal point precision. Is there any way?

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify where are your sub totals and grand total? Its not very clear from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to set precision and convert values to strings so that column types would be same. But do you really need that?

```
SELECT 
    Value1,
    case 
        when StateName is null and [Group] is null then cast(cast(Value1 as decimal(20, 2)) as varchar(30)) 
        when StateName is null and [Group] is not null then cast(cast(Value1 as decimal(20, 1)) as varchar(30)) 
        else cast(cast(Value1 as decimal(20, 2)) as varchar(30)) 
    end 
FROM T  
ORDER BY [Group]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. You can set precision on whole column. You can specify different formatting to different rows within one column. You specify formatting column-wise. Pivoting your result wuold help in your case.